# pdo exception: to many connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I havs a class named Server.php. In that class i have a function that connect to my database. I have already try to extend max_connections, but it didn't solve the issue. Can also say that if i remove one function that connects to my database the problem dissapears. Can someone tell me what the problem can be?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is you have too many open database connections.

Comment: Are you ever closing connections?  If you are calling the function that connects to the DB over and over again, but never close the connections, then you will eventually get an exception.

Comment: How do  you close the connection without to set the variable to null?

Answer (score 1):

Every PDO instance is a seperate connection, so if a function makes a connection to the database, a connection is created every single time it is called. Possible solutions are, in order of preference:

1. `Dependancy Injection`: give a PDO instance as an argument, or in the case of objects, as an object property.
2. Make the PDO instance a `Singleton`.
3. Make the PDO instance a `static` inside the function if that's the only point you use it.
4. Create a `global` variable with the connection.

Comment: But can you store pdo connections in a static or global variable?

Comment: Yes, you can, that's why I mentioned them as possibilities.

Comment: But when i changed it to a static variable i get the error: 'Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted'

Comment: I cannot debug that without code. Post a minimal case to pastebin or codepad et al., and I'll see if I have the time to take a look at it.

Comment: That does not look that bad, I assume you call `Server::connect()` once, and only once, not more (or you can surround that with `if(!self::$pdo instanceof PDO){/*only then create */}`? The rest of the tidbit does seem perfectly workable, and I almost assume the running out of memory is a loop you introduced somewhere, or just gathering massive amounts of data in another logical error.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

connect to mysql:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if ($link) { // here all your operations
    }
```

close  connection:

```
mysql_close($link);
```